# Load JSON file in alphabetical order - Django

Tags: python, json, django

With this method:

```
def postcodes(request):
    with open('core/stores.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
        return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

I load a local json file into this url:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('stores/', views.postcodes, name='postcodes'),
]
```

It renders flawlessly, now, my json file looks like this:

```
[
{
    "name": "St_Albans",
    "postcode": "AL1 2RJ"
},
{
    "name": "Hatfield",
    "postcode": "AL9 5JP"
},
{
    "name": "Worthing",
    "postcode": "BN14 9GB"
},
```

And so on...

As You can see, this is in alphabetical order, if You take into account the postcodes.

What I need, is to read this file, and render it in alphabetical order, but not as it is (by `postcode`), but by `name`.

I don't think I can use the builtin Django loops or tags for this, since they work with models or stored data mostly.

But I'm not completely sure.

What could be a quicker approach to this, instead of saving everything into a database?

I took a look into `serializers` but that's for `django-rest-framework` I'm using plain `requests` here.

Any ideas?

I'm not using any template right now, it is just rendered on browser as it is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can order the list with `.sort(..)`:

```
import json
from operator import itemgetter

def postcodes(request):
    with open('core/stores.json') as f:
        data = json.load(f)
    data.sort(key=itemgetter('name'))
    return JsonResponse(data, safe=False)
```

This will then render the content as:

```
[
    {"name": "Hatfield", "postcode": "AL9 5JP"},
    {"name": "St_Albans", "postcode": "AL1 2RJ"},
    {"name": "Worthing", "postcode": "BN14 9GB"}
]
```

Note that if you want to fetch the postcodes *always* in alphabetical order, it might be better to simply sort the `stores.json` file, already in that order.

Comment: Yeah, thought about that as well (sorting the stores in stores.json), but I'm learning how to do this from a local file, so it's of huge help to know this. Thank You very much.